# property_exists doesn't work on class property which is generated dynamically

Tags: php

I have the following PHP class, which its properties is generated dynamically during running time.

```
<?php

class ParamEx
{
    private $params = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->params[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->params[$name] = $value;
    }
};

$paramEx = new ParamEx();
$property = "dummy_property";
$paramEx->$property = "123";

// "123" printed
echo $paramEx->$property . "\n";

// Nothing printed
echo property_exists($paramEx, $property) . "\n";
```

I realize `property_exists` doesn't work for such case.

Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: Property exists is expecting `$this->property`, your getter/setter is storing it within an array of `$this->params`, you will need to write your own `property_exists` method to test `$this->params[property]`

Comment: Also from the documentation... _The property_exists() function cannot detect properties that are magically accessible using the __get magic method._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I'd add a public method to this class like this:

```
public function propertyExists($property) { return property_exists($this, $property) || isset($this->params[$property]); }
```

If you have a lot of classes like this (and you're using php 5.4 or better), you might want to consider doing this function as a Trait which you can use in all of those classes.

Answer (score 3):

You could overload `__isset` and use `isset($paramEx->$property)` since you're already overloading `__get` and `__set`:

```
class ParamEx
{
    private $params = array();

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->params[$name];
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->params[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __isset($name) {
        return isset($this->params[$name]);
    }
};
```

Then use:

```
echo isset($paramEx->$property) . "\n";
```

instead of:

```
// Nothing printed
echo property_exists($paramEx, $property) . "\n";
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer unless you really need to differentiate between your dynamic properties and others (which seems highly unlikely).